# Can PostgreSQL json index arrays using b-tree indices?

Tags: json, postgresql, indexing

I tested the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    obj jsonb NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (obj)
VALUES('{ "a": "foo", "b": ["cat" , "dog", "horse"]}'),
      ('{ "a": "bar", "b": ["cat" , "dog", "mouse"]}'),
      ('{ "a": "baz", "b": ["dog" , "pig", "cow"]}');
      
create index on test (((obj #>> '{a}')), ((obj #>> '{b}')) );     

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE  (obj #>> '{a}') = 'bar'  AND  (obj #> '{b}') ? 'mouse';
```

Actually I inserted a couple of thousand rows just to make sure pg will use indices where possible.

My hope was that the query would use both paths of the index. It does not. Even if I replace the index definition with:

```
create index on test (((obj #>> '{a}')), ((obj #> '{b}')) );
```

it  will use only the {a} part of the definition, and then use filtering for the {b} part of my query.

I know at least one (xml) database, that with a btree index definition on an element that occurs multiple times will just put a key in the index for each occurrence (in combination with the rest of the indexed values). Sure, this yields a big index, but queries are nice and fast.

Of course for pg/json, I can use a GIN index, but in general I prefer multiple targeted indexes.

So, my question is twofold:

- What exactly does it mean for pg/json when I create an index according to the above statement(s)? Because pg happily accepts the creation of the index, no errors.
- Is it at all possible to index an array using a btree index and have it support queries with array-contains predicates?

Comment: How many rows returns for the query `obj #>> '{a}') = 'bar'`.

Comment: GIN indexes are created for exactly this use case.

Comment: 0 rows are returned if I try the "= 'bar'" query. That predicate is actually what you would use in xquery/xml for this type of search, and which is supported in the XML database I was referring to through b-tree indices.

Answer (score 0):

A b-tree index cannot be used, because you are searching for array elements.

Get reconciled with GIN indexes and modify the query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON test USING gin (obj);

SELECT * FROM test
WHERE obj @> '{ "a": "bar", "b": [ "mouse" ] }';
```

If you don't like GIN indexes, you shouldn't be using JSON.

Comment: I only had a preference for one over the other :-), so I just wanted to verify. GIN indices it is then. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @Mark: the big advantage of the GIN index is that you only need one which covers a wide range of query predicates. You don't have to create new indices each time you have new types of queries. That index could also be used if you add more keys and want to query for them. Or if you rename the keys.